# Interval Arithmetic with Symbolic Intervals

Tags: symbolic, regions, intervals

I've run into a problem with `IntervalUnion` and `IntervalIntersection` when dealing with symbolic intervals.

The following code should give `Interval[{a,b},{c,d}]`

```
IntervalUnion[Interval[{a, b}], Interval[{c, d}]]
```

...however it spits itself back unevaluated. The same goes for:

```
IntervalIntersection[Interval[{a, b}], Interval[{c, d}]]
```

Which one would hope generates another `Interval`, yet again is unevaluated. But everything is fine as long as you use numbers, for instance:

```
IntervalIntersection[Interval[{1.2, 3.9}], Interval[{2.6, 5.1}]]
```

... gives the expected `Interval[{2.6, 3.9}]`. It seems counterintuitive that I can't use them with symbols. I came across this when trying to find the shared support of two probability distributions (which does nothing):

```
IntervalIntersection @@ (DistributionDomain /@ 
 {TriangularDistribution[{0, k}, 0], UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]})

(*Result: IntervalIntersection[Interval[{0, k}], Interval[{0, 1}]]  *)
```

I'd hope to see the result `Interval[{0,Min[1,k]}]` or is that asking too much of Mathematica to generate assumptions on the `k`? Mathematica is already good at generating piecewise functions for variables assumptions in many other contexts, but not here. Something like this would be incredibly useful, especially if you wanted to do symbolic integration restricted to the intersection of lots of symbolic intervals without going through them all or generating a big list of `x∈s1 && x∈s2 && x∈s3 ...` constraints.

Comment: I've been trawling through the documentation and there is no mention of intervals with symbols, only numbers and Infinity... so it's presumably unimplemented.

Comment: Does `Reduce[x \[Element] RegionUnion[Interval[{a, b}], Interval[{c, d}]], {x, a, b, c, d}, Reals]` bring you any closer?  `Reduce` did not work on `IntervalUnion`, btw.

Comment: @MichaelE2 while it does produce constraints, no Interval. I'll have to use this as a workaround unless anybody has successfully found a way to do it with `Assumptions`, or some internal undocumented feature.  It's easy enough to roll your own interval arithmetic functions but we shouldn't have to (as it appears Wolfram have already done it for numerics but not symbols)

Comment: This might have something to do with the fact that everything is taken to be complex-valued unless explicitly told otherwise. What if you wrap things in an `Assuming[]` with the necessary assertions?

Comment: Note that the x-sub-1 in the output is actually `Indexed[x, {1}]`, which makes no sense to me.  I have no idea how to make `Interval` work in the way you'd like.

Comment: OK, this produces a better result, but I don't why we have to use `{x}`: `Reduce[{x} \[Element] RegionUnion[Interval[{a, b}], Interval[{c, d}]] && x \[Element] Reals, {x, a, b, c, d}, Reals]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. still just prints itself. I tried doing an internal trace but it got me nowhere. I'm thinking that while this may not necessarially be a bug since the documentation doesn't mention symbolic interval endpoints, this is an overlooked feature that could potentially confuse a lot of users.

Comment: Some evidence that *M* does not do much with symbolic intervals: `FullSimplify[IntervalUnion[Interval[{a, b}], Interval[{a, b}]]]` returns `IntervalUnion[Interval[{a, b}], Interval[{a, b}]]`.  However, `RegionUnion` works as one would expect.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yup I'll be using RegionUnion/Intersection in the meantime, thanks.

Comment: A shame this still doesn't work 5 years later!